# Python Circular Import Module _gi causes apt-add-repository command to fail in linux

Tags: python-3.x, linux, terminal, apt

I was trying to add a repository today when i find a strange error that i cannot seem to solve.

I was trying to do this command

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:fish-shell/release-3
```

When it always returned this error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/apt-add-repository", line 11, in <module>
    from softwareproperties.SoftwareProperties import SoftwareProperties, shortcut_handler
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/SoftwareProperties.py", line 67, in <module>
    from gi.repository import Gio
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/__init__.py", line 42, in <module>
    from . import _gi
ImportError: cannot import name '_gi' from partially initialized module 'gi' (most likely due to a circular import) (/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/__init__.py)
```

I've tried diagnosing it with this command

```
 sudo update-alternatives --config python3
```

and it shows this

```
There is only one alternative in link group python3 (providing /usr/bin/python3): /usr/bin/python3.8
Nothing to configure.
```

I've also tried going to the /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi
and adding a symbolic link there with this command

```
sudo ln -s _gi.cpython-{36m,37m}-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
```

Still it didn't work

I've tried adding the correct python version to /usr/bin/apt-add-repository

I have also tried to use

```
python3 -m pip install gi
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement gi (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for gi
```

How do i fix this annoying error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

done:

```
sudo apt-get install graphviz
```

And the code:

```
import objgraph
import random
import io
from graphviz import Source
from io import StringIO

q = StringIO()

#objgraph.show_refs([SAFE_TAGS], output=s)

objgraph.show_chain(
    objgraph.find_backref_chain(
        random.choice(objgraph.by_type('dict')),
        objgraph.is_proper_module),
    output=q)

q.seek(0)
Source(q.read())
```

[chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ArJcP.png)

Comment: I'm sorry but how could this be the accepted response to the question?